# Подвижная панель с закрепкой в jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

У меня есть панель. При наведении курсора в левую границу монитора, она появляется. Когда убираешь с ее поверхности мышку - она опять прячется. Это все сделал и работает. Вопрос:

Хочу ставить внизу булавку, чтобы при нажатии на нее панель при убирании мыши не пряталась. А оставалась фиксированной. Как можно сделать такое?

```js
var width = document.width;
var height = document.height;

$('#top_line').css({
    'width': 'width'
});

$('#top_panel').css({
    'width': width
});

$('#open_btn').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#profile_pic').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#notifications').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#border').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#settings').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#search').css({
    'right': width / 12
});

$('#profile_menu').css({
    'right': width / 13.3
});

$('#triangle').css({
    'right': width / 11.5
});

$('#down_press').click(function () {
    $('#down').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $('#down_press').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $('#close').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });

    $('#profile_menu').animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 150);

    $('#triangle').animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 150);
});

$('#close').click(function () {
    $('#down').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });

    $('#down_press').css({
        'display': 'block',
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': '-8px'
    });

    $('#close').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $('#profile_menu').animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 150);

    $('#triangle').animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 150);
});

$('#close').focusout(function () {
    $('#down').css({
        'display': 'block'
    });

    $('#down_press').css({
        'display': 'block',
            'position': 'relative',
            'top': '-8px'
    });

    $('#close').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $('#profile_menu').animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 150);

    $('#triangle').animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 150);
});

$('#slide_panel').css({
    'height': height - 65
});

$('#slide_border').css({
    'height': height - 65
});

$('#slide_border').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#slide_panel').animate({
        'left': 0
    }, 200)
});

$('#slide_panel').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#slide_panel').animate({
        'left': '-215px'
    }, 200)
});

$('#ribbon').css({
    'top': height / 2 - 80
});

$('#slide_menu').css({
    'height': height - 65
});

$('#chat_panel').css({
    'height': height - 64
});

$('#chat_border').css({
    'height': height - 65
});

$('#pin').css({
    'bottom': -(height / 3) - 40
});

$('#pin').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#pin').css({
        'opacity': '1',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
    })
});

$('#pin').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#pin').css({
        'opacity': '0.4',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
    })
});
```

```css
#slide_panel {
    position:absolute;
    top:64px;
    left:-215px;
    width:215px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 2;
}
#slide_border {
    position:relative;
    top:-1px;
    left:215px;
    width:5px;
    background-color:#e1695b;
    z-index:2;
}
#ribbon {
    position:absolute;
    left:180px;
    z-index:1;
    height:80px;
    width:78px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.slide_menu {
    font-size:14px;
    color: #737373;
    width:214px;
    position:relative;
    left:-184px;
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    line-height:15px;
    z-index: 2;
}
hr {
    color:#737373;
    height:2px;
    width:212px;
    position:relative;
    left:-215px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
#menu_div {
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #wall {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#wall {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wall_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#wall p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -25px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#wall:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#wall:hover {
    background-clip: 5px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #profile {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#profile:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
#profile_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#profile p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#profile:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #friends {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#friends_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#friends p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#friends:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#friends:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #photos {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#photos_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#photos p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#photos:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#photos:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #book_list {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#book_list_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#book_list p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#book_list:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#book_list:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #quotes {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#quotes_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#quotes p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#quotes:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#quotes:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #download {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#download_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#download p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#download:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#download:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #recenzii {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#recenzii_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#recenzii p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#recenzii:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#recenzii:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #events {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#events_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#events p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#events:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#events:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
/* --------------------------------------------------------- */
 #setting {
    height: 44px;
    width: 215px;
    position: relative;
    left: -215px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#setting_ico {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
#setting p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font: Roboto, arial, sans-serif;
    color: #737373;
    width: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 11px;
    margin-left: 36px;
}
#setting:hover p {
    color: #262626;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#setting:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<div id="slide_panel">
 <div id="slide_border">
      <div id="wall">
             <img id="wall_ico" src="img/wall.gif" />
       <p>Лента</p>
            </div>
            
     <div id="menu_div">

         <div id="profile">
          <p>Профиль</p>
             <img id="profile_ico" src="img/profile_ico.gif" />
            </div>
            
            <div id="friends">
            <p>Друзья</p>
               <img id="friends_ico" src="img/friends.gif" />
            </div>
        
        <div id="photos">
         <p>Фото</p>
            <img id="photos_ico" src="img/photo.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="book_list">
         <p>Список моих книг</p>
            <img id="book_list_ico" src="img/book_list.gif" />
        </div>

          <hr>

        <div id="quotes">        
         <p>Цитаты из книг</p>
            <img id="quotes_ico" src="img/quotes.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="download">        
            <p>Скачать Книги</p>
            <img id="download_ico" src="img/download.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="recenzii">        
            <p>Рецензии</p>
            <img id="recenzii_ico" src="img/recenzii.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="events">        
            <p>Мероприятия</p>
            <img id="events_ico" src="img/events.gif" />
        </div>

        <div id="setting">        
            <p>Настройки</p>
            <img id="setting_ico" src="img/setting.gif" />
        </div>

        <img id="pin" src="img/pin.gif" />

        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="ribbon" src="img/ribbon.gif" />
</div>
```

[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/R4Q8S/)

Comment: Создаём переменную, в которой будем хранить, зафиксирована ли панель. Анимации появления и исчезагния панели делаем только если она не закреплена. Значение переменной меняем на противоположное по клику на булавку. Что конкретно из вышеперечисленного вызывает затруднения?

Comment: делал, но не получается =/

Comment: @navi1893 ну можно было бы код привести, что именно ты "все сделал и работает". Тут же нет экстрасенсов :)

Comment: я код удалил уже. Но захотел через булин сделать, но когда создаю булеву переменную, то вся страница(JS часть) деформируется =/

Comment: С этого момента, пожалуйста, поподробнее. Как именно нужно было создать булеву переменную, чтобы деформировать страницу? Постарайтесь воспроизвести это чудо и выложить на jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/quKX5/ я новичок в JS, можно и по проще сделать но вроде работает!